# Mysql database doesn't get deleted after deleting a user fully privileged on it

Tags: mysql

I've created an authorized, all privileged DB user, including a DB with the same name:

```
create user 'test'@'localhost' identified by 'blablabla';
create database test;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON test.* TO test@localhost;
show grants for 'test'@'localhost';
```

I then did `drop user 'test'@'localhost';` and `show databases;` afterwards, seeing that even though the user `test` was deleted, the DB with the same name still existed.

**How can this be?** When I dropped users with P**HPmyadmin**, their DB's where deleted as well (if I recall correctly it happened totally naturally), so why do I still have the database if I deleted its associated user?

<sub>Note: By "associated user" I mean to the user with full privileges on that database).</sub>

I had the thought that given other users could access the DB, it shouldn't be deleted. I might confuse a PHPmyadmin option to delete any DB associated with the dropped user, with deleting the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other users (e.g. the one that created it) might have access to the database, so why should it be deleted by a `DROP USER`?

Comment: You are right, of course, I had the thought that given other users could access the DB, it must not be deleted. I might confuse an option to delete any DB associated with the dropped user, with deleting the user. This seems to come from the wrong paradigm I had that "if one creates a DB user and a samely named DB, than they will always be tied together".

Comment: Think of databases + users as completely separate entities. Deleting/Dropping one has no effect on the other.